# Visually distinguishing Visual Studio 2010 windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Imagine I have two branches (`default` and `production`) of the same solution "checked out" locally. Now, when I open these two in Visual Studio there's absolutely no way to distinguish them at a glance. Is there any way I can configure Visual Studio to somehow differentiate solutions opened from different paths? Think SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rename Visual Studio Window Title](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f3f23845-5b1e-4811-882f-60b7181fa6d6) seems to do almost what I need. Changing settings to `1-2-2-False` seem to produce decent results.

And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577188/how-to-change-the-title-bar-text-of-visual-studio) more to that end.