# Quickest way to check what project is loaded in VS2013

Tags: tfs, ide, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution that exists in multiple branches and multiple workspaces in TFS. When editing them in Visual Studio, they all look very similar. It is not uncommon for me to have multiple versions of the solution open at the same time in separate instances of Visual Studio. Three or four is not uncommon when tracing changes between branches. It can get confusing to know which solution is which.

What is the quickest way to tell which specific solution (file path or branch and workspace) I have loaded in VS2013?

My current approach is to open a file and hover over its tab to see the file location, but when I am Alt-tabbing through multiple instances of VS, this is tedious.

Comment: You could change the window titles: some options for doing that in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577188/how-to-change-the-title-bar-text-of-visual-studio)

Comment: @Blorgbeard that's better than what I was hoping for. I'll give it a whirl. Did you want to put your comment as an answer rather than a comment so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: Wellll stackoverflow frowns on answers that are just links to other questions. If you get what you need from that question, I'd suggest you just vote to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: The dilemma with that is that I didn't find the other question/answer using the search terms I tried. So hopefully by keeping this question and linked answer it may be found by someone using similar search terms to mine!

Comment: Upvoted questions closed as dupe are not deleted, they're still considered useful as redirects - as you noted.