# Stop Visual Studio solution titles showing as localhost_12312 etc

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide

For various reasons we are using VS2013 as our preferred IDE to edit php and html pages.

These are websites running on WAMP, so VS2013 is just IDE for us, nothing else. These aren't web solutions or web projects. There's no IIS or ASP. We just do "open website" and just point to the local folder containing the website files.

If we have multiple instances open it's hard to tell them apart as VS2013 captions the windows as localhost_12312, localhost_45645 etc

Here's what it looks like in the taskbar:

[image]

Tried installing Erwin Mayer's addon mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5681161/180430) but that just results in the title bar showing as:

```
localhost_12312\localhost_12312 - Microsoft Visual Studio *
```

Is there a fix for this annoying niggle?

Comment: Its just an educated guess but have you tried changing "Farthest parent folder depth" attribute to be higher than original value in Erwin Mayer's addon settings?

Answer (score 6):

If the Mentioned method in my comment doesn't support your question, you can use the following vs extension: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e8ebfe4-023f-4c4d-9b7a-d05bbc5cb239

Use the **Expression language operators and their precedence section** to help you build the required behavior.

For example you can do something like this:

```
> if (sln_filename) {
    sln_filename + " - Visual Studio " + vs_version + " " + vs_edition
} else {
    // do whatever you want if there is no solution open
    "Visual Studio " + vs_version + " " + vs_edition
}
```

I hope it supports your question

Answer (score 0):

Check this extension [VSCommands for Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece) and it features to rename instance [Click Here for details](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features-SolutionBadges#manual)