# How do I easily identify different branches of the same codebase in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, projects-and-solutions

We have three branches of our codebase in TFS2010 - dev, main and release. During the course of my week I do a lot of jumping between solutions for the different branches e.g. fix something, do some new dev, fix something else and so on.

Without opening the project folder in Windows Explorer its very hard to ascertain what is open in the IDE and I was wondering if there are workarounds for this in VS2010 (this question was asked some time ago ([https://stackoverflow.com/q/523637/287254](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523637/working-with-different-versions-branches-of-the-same-visual-studio-2005-solution)) - but was for VS2005, I'm hoping there are newer, less hacky fixes for the latest version of VS/TFS).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The VSCommands extension has a feature called 'friendly solution name' which allows you to show the branch in the main title. The feature is available in the lite version.
[VSCommands features](http://vscommands.com/features/)

Comment: Where is the solution name stored?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it out today. Will accept this if nothing more lightweight turns up.

Comment: ACCEPTED.

VSCommands is just *brilliant*. And free. Many thanks!

Comment: Had VSCommands on all the time but never really realised this feature existed!! :D Great, simply great!